# Multiple choices command line argument

Tags: python, command-line, argparse, multiple-choice

How could a multiple choices argument in the command line be implemented? There would be a predefined set of options and the user can choose multiple:

```
python cli.py --alphabet upper,lower,digits,symbols
```

or

```
python cli.py --alphabet upper lower digits symbols
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs

Example:

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='game.py')
>>> parser.add_argument('--move', choices=['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'], nargs="+")
>>> parser.parse_args(['--move', 'rock', 'paper'])
Namespace(move=['rock', 'paper'])
>>> parser.parse_args(['--move','fire'])
usage: game.py [-h] [--move {rock,paper,scissors} [{rock,paper,scissors} ...]]
game.py: error: argument --move: invalid choice: 'fire' (choose from 'rock', 'paper', 'scissors')
```

Answer (score 4):

From [Variable Argument Lists](https://pymotw.com/2/argparse/#variable-argument-lists) of [`argparse`](https://pymotw.com/3/argparse/) in [Python 3 Module of the Week](https://pymotw.com/3/):

> You can configure a single argument definition to consume multiple arguments on the command line being parsed. Set `nargs` to one of these flag values, based on the number of required or expected arguments:

So in your case you need to supply

```
parser.add_argument('--alphabet', nargs='+')
```

Which would stand for *All, and at least one, argument*

And then call it with:

```
python cli.py --alphabet upper lower digits symbols
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use some options parser is the second choice

- https://github.com/docopt/docopt
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html